Is it a sin if someone kills a person who wanted to kill him?
Is it a sin if someone kills a person who wanted to kill him? There could be many such situations in life. Suppose a person is trying to kill me or rob me, in self-defence, if I kill the person before he inflicts damage on me, is that a sin according to Hindu sastras?

No, it is not a sin as stated in the following Manu Smriti verses:

8.348. Twice-born men may take up arms when (they are) hindered (in the fulfilment of their duties, when destruction (threatens) the
twice-born castes (varna) in (evil) times,
8.349. In their own defence, in a strife for the fees of officiating priests, and in order to protect women and Brahmanas; he who (under
such circumstances) kills in the cause of right, commits no sin
8.350. One may slay without hesitation an assassin who approaches (with murderous intent), whether (he be one’s) teacher, a child or an
aged man, or a Brahmana deeply versed in the Vedas.
8.351. By killing an assassin the slayer incurs no guilt, whether (he does it) publicly or secretly; in that case fury recoils upon fury.


It is not a sin even as per Vasista Dharma Sutra


They declare that the slayer commits no crime by killing an assassin.

Now they quote also (the following verses): 'An incendiary, likewise a poisoner, one who holds a weapon in his hand (ready to
kill), a robber, he who takes away land, and he who abducts (another
man's) wife, these six are called assassins (ātatāyin).'

'He may slay an assassin who comes with the intention of slaying, even though he knows the whole Veda together with the Upaniṣads; by
that (act) he (does) not (incur the guilt of) the slayer of a
Brāhmaṇa.'

'He who slays an assassin learned in the Veda and belonging to a noble family, does not incur by that act the guilt of the murderer of
a learned Brāhmaṇa.; (in) that (case) fury recoils upon fury.'


VDS Chapter 3

